# Saving images to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Hello i am currently able to save images to my server using this function:

```
    HttpPostedFile filePosted = CategoryImage.PostedFile;
            string fullPath = "";

            if (filePosted != null && filePosted.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                int contentLength = CategoryImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                string contentType = CategoryImage.PostedFile.ContentType;

                string filename = filePosted.FileName;
                string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

                fullPath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/img/logos/", filename));

                if (fileextension == ".jpg" || fileextension == ".jpeg" || fileextension == ".png" || fileextension == ".bmp")
                {
                    CategoryImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullPath);
                }
            }
```

But the image path in my database gets saved as this:

```
D:\Projects\*************\****\img\logos\image1.png
```

Now when i assign this path to an html img "src" attribute the image does not display. i get no errors when running my code, preferrably i would like the path to be something like this:

```
~/******/img/image1.png
```

The image displays when i use the format above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute the full path by the relative one and insert it in the src attribute.

```
string s1 = @"D:\Projects\*************\****\img\logos\image1.png";            
string s2 = "~/****/" + s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf("img")).Replace("\\", "/");
// use s2 as src attribute for img
```

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application

Have you tried using just fullPath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("/img/logos/", filename))

Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

I think with "/" this will place your images in a folder that IIS can access rather then the D: folder